# Search for record in database "Java.lang.NullPointerExepton"

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to search for the id of a movie in a table of the database. I'm new to database connection and new to java as well.  This code doesn't have error in my form but I created a record of id '1' and always gives me this error "Java.lang.NullPointerExepton".

I have the record with that id but always have that error. Any help will be appreciated

```
Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;

        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // TODO add your handling code here:

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project";
            String userid = "root";
            String password = "";

    try{
                String sql="SELECT Movie_idMovie FROM rental_movie"
                        + "WHERE Movie_idMovie =?";
                pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
                rs=pst.executeQuery();
                if(rs.next()){
                    String add1=rs.getString("Movie_idMovie");
                    jTextField2.setText(add1);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace, the message that shows `NullPointerException`.

Comment: But looking at your code, looks like `Connection con` is `null`. Where do you initialize it?

Comment: First time that I hear form stacktrace. I only put that code...didn't initialize somewhere else.

Comment: Add `e.printStacktrace()` inside the `catch` block statement.

Comment: Thanks I'll keep that in mind next time I get some error. Useful tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is this:

```
Connection conn = null;

String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project";
String userid = "root";
String password = "";

pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

You missed the important step of actually opening the connection, leaving `conn` null when you try and use it. Try adding the following, before you call `conn.prepare...`

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userid, password);
```

Comment: Now it says… "com.mysql.jbdc.exceptions.jbdc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:  You have an error in you SQL syntax;check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near’=’1 at line1."

Comment: You need a space before 'WHERE'.

Comment: @Marve that's another problem and it's outside this question scope. Anyway, looks like you have/need to check your query.

Comment: Solved!! I changed this
String sql="SELECT * FROM rental_movie WHERE Movie_idMovie = ?";